# focus() not working - why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have nested body elements and iframes. One from my html page, and one from the TinyMce. To the body of the tinymce I append div with many textboxes. Their ids are hi1, hi2 etc.

This code:

```
$($('#petko_ifr').focus().contents()).find('#dishComments').find('#' + e.target.id)
```

returns the correct input element (textbox) and it has a focus method. But this:

```
$($('#petko_ifr').focus().contents()).find('#myDiv').find('#hi1').focus()
```

doesn't focus! This:

```
$($('#petko_ifr').focus().contents()).find('#myDiv').find('#hi1').val('somethingg')
```

works fine. Why is this happening and how to solve this?

In Chrome, when I inspect the element (click in the html code  and when I click visually on the textbox it is clicked. But when I'm not inspecting the element the click isn't working.

Comment: have you tried setting the .val to $(this).val(), it doesnt seem a nice way to do it but it could be a quick work around?

Comment: @RoryPickering But val() isn't the proble. focus() is the problem